# How to display only subcategories in layered navigation?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, php, layered-navigation

`Layered Navigation` shows all `categories`. I have the category structure as below:

```
-Default Category(8)
    -Flowers(5)
       Rose(2)
       Lotus(3)
    -Fruits(3)
       Apple(2)
       Orange(0)
       Grapes(1)
```

If I click the category **Fruits** from the main navigation all categories are displayed in layered navigation. Like this:

```
   Flowers
   Rose
   Lotus
   Fruits
   Apple
   Orange
   Grapes
```

But I need to `display only the subcategories of the selected category` (here **Fruits**) in `layered navigation`. Expected result is:

```
Apple
Orange
Grapes
```

How can I do this?

To display `layered navigation` what I did is: **In Catalog > Manage Categories >  (Category name) > Display settings** change `Is Anchor` to `Yes`.

Comment: can you show us code?

Comment: I not change any code(i don't know how to change)

Comment: how you able to get all categories?

Comment: when I apply layered navigation all categories are displayed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the answer!!!

In `app\design\frontend\[template]\[template]\layout\catalog.xml`  in *Category layered navigation layout* section,

I changed

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav1" before="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml"/>
```

to

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav1" before="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
```

And now its working as required.

Comment: Hi, I am using Magento2.1  I want to display categories in layeed navigation.Can you guide me where I can use this code?